# Color specific Row in ListView with JavaFX

Tags: css, listview, javafx, colors, row

I'm working with JavaFX and a ListView of String, for example i got 10 row in this list, with a specific validation in an another function i got an error on the row 3 and 7.

What i want is to color in Red the cell's background on row 3 and 7 in order to show to my user that this row/line are not good.

I check setCellfactory and i @Override the updateItem but i cannot find how to color multiple specific row/line.

I don't know how to select this row in order to put a different CSS style or simply color it in Java.

Thank in advance for your help.

EDITED

Actually i'm trying to do this thing like that ...

```
 ListViewCenter().setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>,   ListCell<String>>() {

        @Override
        public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
            final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < Analyse.linesErrorsList.size(); i++) {

                if (cell.getIndex() == Analyse.linesErrorsList.get(i)) {

                    cell.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:red;");

                }

            }

            return cell;
        }
    });
```

My Analyse.linesErrorsList is the list of lines that are in errors ...

EDITED

One solution is

```
listViewCenter().setCellFactory(list -> {
// usual list cell:
ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty); 
        setText(empty ? null : item);
    }
};

BooleanBinding invalid = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
    () -> Analyse.linesErrorsList.contains(new Integer(cell.getIndex())),
    cell.indexProperty(), Analyse.linesErrorsList
);

invalid.addListener((obs, wasInvalid, isNowInvalid) -> {
    if (isNowInvalid) {
        cell.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:red;");
    } else {
        cell.setStyle("");
    }
});

return cell ;
});
```

@James_D Could you help me again plz, i got an issue when i scroll down to the end of the list and go back to the start ...

Apparently my Listview call the CellFactory but it doesn't use my @Override of the CellFactory ... my listview seems to use the default one ...

How can i tell my listview to use my @Override of the CellFactory ... 
Thanks in advance ...

EDITED

So this is my MINIMAL code to show you :)

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.BooleanBinding;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class thisMy extends Application {

static ListView<String> listview;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    listview = new ListView<String>();
    ObservableList<String> listOfString = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ObservableList<Integer> errorList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        listOfString.add("This my line" + i);
    }

    errorList.addAll(0, 2, 5, 78, 598, 124, 368, 888, 997, 614, 741);
    listview.setItems(listOfString);

    listview.setCellFactory(list -> {
        // usual list cell:
        ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(empty ? null : item);
            }
        };

        BooleanBinding invalid = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
                () -> errorList.contains(new Integer(cell.getIndex())), cell.indexProperty(), cell.itemProperty(),
                errorList);

        invalid.addListener((obs, wasInvalid, isNowInvalid) -> {
            if (isNowInvalid) {
                cell.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:red;");
            } else {
                cell.setStyle("");
            }
        });

        return cell;
    });

    primaryStage.setTitle("Test for listview");
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(listview);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: What is `Analyse.linesErrorsList`?Is it an observable list? Is it possible for a valid value to be changed so it is invalid, or vice-versa, and in that case will `Analyse.linesErrorsList` automatically update?

Comment: Yes it's an observable list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
listViewCenter().setCellFactory(list -> new ListCell<String>() {

    BooleanBinding invalid ;

    {
        invalid = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
            () -> Analyse.linesErrorsList.contains(new Integer(getIndex())),
            indexProperty(), itemProperty(), Analyse.linesErrorsList
        );

        invalid.addListener((obs, wasInvalid, isNowInvalid) -> {
            if (isNowInvalid) {
                setStyle("-fx-text-fill:red;");
            } else {
                setStyle("");
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty); 
        setText(empty ? null : item);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but there is something missing in the BooleanBinding line at the end ... Eclipse is saying to me that something is missing here

Comment: Had a couple of typos: think those are fixed now.

Comment: Thanks man your rox :)

I have to understand your code better ^^ 
I'm only coding since 4 month :)

Comment: do you have any solution for my problem @James_D ?

I don't understand how to tell my listview to use evrytime my Override of CellFactory ... my listview use my Override only one time at the start ... 

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in your latest edit. Probably you need to provide a complete example. See [MCVE].

Comment: I think i understand my problem, i don't override the call() method so the cell.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:red;"); is only called once but not evrytime the listview need to render the cell 

I'm looking right now how to override the call() method in Javadoc , quite difficult for a debutant, only 3 month of code here ;) 

Thanks for evrythin

Comment: It should be called when the index of the cell changes. If you need it to update when the item changes without the index changing, add `cell.indexProperty()` to the list of dependencies for `invalid`.

Comment: You already put cell.indexProperty() in your code, but when the cell need to be rendered again it use the default cell factory not mine :( 

So i think Override the call() method is the solution or maybe i' missunderstood somethin :)

Comment: Sorry, I mean add `cell.itemProperty()` to the list... I don't know what you mean by using the default cell factory; you have set a new cell factory, so it will always use that.

Comment: Thank you man but The way my listview refresh cell is weird , like the index of the cell are not the same evrytime etc, now with cell.itemProperty , the cell in Red change sometimes and sometimes not , it's weird ! 

I surely missunderstood the way index are generates or something like that 

I keep my search on

Comment: As I said before, you need to post a [MCVE].

Comment: ok so when i set my CellFactory it use it evrytime, so my problem is with the index detection, i'm making big progress with you, tanks James

Comment: ok i understand i'm writing a Minimal code to show you, i need some minutes

Comment: I edited my question with a Minimal view, when you launch it you can see that the number from errorList are in RED but when you go down and go up the line in RED are not the same it's quite weird. i think i got an problem with the index reference or something like this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ah, yuck. The binding is getting garbage collected because there is no valid reference to it once the cell factory has been invoked (i.e. once all the cells have been created). You need to move the binding to be an instance variable in the cell. See updated version.

Comment: Thanks man you're a star of the code ! 
Can i ask you when do you start coding ? 

You seems very experienced !

Comment: Start coding? Entirely? I don't really ever remember not coding, but it was probably 1979 or something..

Comment: Wow ! I understand why your skills are so high, thanks and cya ;)